# Natural logarithmic definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I proceed to calculating the integral

> > $$\int_0^1 \dfrac { \ln(1-t) }{t} \space \mathrm{d}t$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @CraigFrost: And obviously there are multiple ways to do this (other then my way), but you didn't specify. Next time give some context to the problem for a better answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a Taylor series, we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}{ \frac{\ln(1-t)}{t} } \,dt &= -\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1+\frac{t}{2} +\frac{t^2}{3} +\frac{t^3}{4} +\frac{t^4}{5}+\ldots \right)}\,dt \\ &= -\left[t+\frac{t^2}{4} +\frac{t^3}{9} +\frac{t^4}{16}+\ldots\right]_{0}^{1} \\ &= -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} \\ &= -\frac{\pi^2}{6} 
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Look up $\zeta(2)$ for the last step.

Comment: See [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: Or directly appealing to the dilogarithm function, we have $$\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\,dt=-\text{Li}_2(1)=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$